# Add two SQL select query results into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a table which contains data for different companies, Let's say:

```
          Field1     Field2     Field3
row1        A1         A2         A3
row2        B1         B2         B3
row3        C1         C2         C3
```

In SSIS, I need to write one query in the OLE DB Source to contain two rows. IT is very complex query containing too many joins, conditions so I can only write one query for one row. 
e.g.:

```
select Field1 from Table where Field2 = A2
```

and

```
select Field 1 from Table where Field2 = B2.
```

If I cannot add `Field2 = A2` or `Field2 = B2`, how can I put those two Select queries to return two rows, e.g. row1 and row2?

THanks!

Comment: tried using `union` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select Field1 from Table where Field2 = A2
union
select Field 1 from Table where Field2 = B2.
```

Union = you will have all the distinct values

```
select Field1 from Table where Field2 = A2
union all
select Field 1 from Table where Field2 = B2.
```

Union All : you will have all the values

Answer (score 0):

```
select Field1 from Table where Field2 IN ('A2', 'B2')
```